# YouTube Video Stopped Working?

Tags: youtube

I have had video stop working on YouTube.

It worked before without an issue and was great, however, today when I tried to play the video it doesn't play at all. I have made no changes to the video and other YouTube videos play without an issue.

When I went into the YouTube Video manager and tried to play it I see the following message:

> An error occurred. Please try again later. [Learn More](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019?p=player_error1&rd=1)

Of course the learn more doesn't really help me any. How do I get this video working again?

[Video link in question.](http://youtu.be/Decb1BnP22M)

Comment: Did you upload the video?     Is there any reason why Google might have removed it, eg did it include any copyright music or content?

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ - No. It was an after effects template from videohive.net which should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From checking the uploader of the video's channel on YouTube, it appears that the video in question has been removed by the uploader.

The relevant error message for this video is as follows:

```
ERROR: content too short (expected 15287800 bytes and served 1323)
```

...in other words the expected size of this video is 14.58MB, but only 1323 bytes was served from the server.

Comment: The video should be that size. And it was at one point. I didn't change anything.